# File uploading via FileAPI

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, fileapi

I need to read multiple files into a single function A. I need to use FileAPI for it.
But FileReader performs an asynchronous download. 
Can I get the contents of all files at the end of function A without exiting, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be perfectly clear, `FileReader` isn't downloading anything. It is asynchronously reading the File contents (as it appears on disk) into memory.

To do what you want, just keep track of the read files and call a callback when they're all done:

```
document.querySelector('[type="file"]').change = function(e) {
  handleFiles(toArray(e.target.files), function(results) {
    // results is an Array containing the FileReader results.
    alert('Done!');
  });

function toArray(list) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(list || [], 0);
}

function handleFiles(files, callback) {
  var results = [];

  files.forEach(function(file, i) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      results.push(e.target.result);
      if (results.length == files.length) {
        callback(results);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
```

Try it: http://jsbin.com/epatel/3/edit#html,live